# Synchronize Chrome bookmarks across multiple machines

Tags: synchronization, google-chrome

#### Update: no longer relevant, please vote to close.

We all know and love [xmarks](http://www.xmarks.com/) for keeping Firefox bookmarks sync'd across computers, but...

Almost everyone at our company has switched to Chrome. Has anyone found any tools to synchronize users' bookmarks in Chrome? What about hacks to the registry and/or user profiles?

Or do we just need to wait for the plug-in model on Chrome 2?

Comment: Belongs to superuser.com

Comment: Why close a question that may be of use to other people in the future?

Comment: Because Chrome now has bookmark sync, built-in.

Answer (score 2):

Just as side note: I'm using the [Delicious](http://www.delicious.com/) service for bookmarking sites. It's browser and machine independant.

From the about page:

> Instead of having different bookmarks
>   on every computer, Delicious makes it
>   easy to have a single set of bookmarks
>   kept in sync between all of your
>   computers. Even if you're not on a
>   computer you own, you can still get to
>   your bookmarks on the Delicious
>   website.

Answer (score 1):

I found [a guide to using the online Google Bookmarks with Chrome](http://metaed.blogspot.com/2008/12/using-google-bookmarks-in-google-chrome.html) that allow them to be searchable. This should also work across computers if you set it up on both.

Answer (score 1):

You can now use [bookmark sync](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?answer=165139)

It is under the the wrench menu and requires Google account as the bookmarks are stored in your Google docs. You can actually see a folder "Google Chrome" and access your bookmarks from Docs.

Answer (score 0):

There is [no plug-in for Google Chrome](http://mashable.com/2009/02/05/google-chrome-extensions-launch-date/), yet. From the source:

> Apparently, a Google developer
>   conference scheduled for May 27th will
>   include a session on developing
>   extensions for Chrome, which leads
>   Google Operating System to conclude
>   that we’ll see the extensions platform
>   go live on or before that date.

Comment: That doesn't preclude someone from writing a tool to sync bookmarks, however.

Answer (score 0):

Is this internally at the company only? If so, the bookmarks should be stored in the user profile (appdata) anyway - so have that redirected to a share for the users, or use roaming profiles?